# What is rude jazz?

Tags: jazz, history, genre

In a lecture supporting his new book Stomp and Shout, Northwest rock historian Peter Blecha mentioned a genre from the 1940s or 50s called rude jazz. I have never heard of this before, and it might be a specifically Northwest thing. Is anyone else aware of such as genre? What is it? He described it as using jazz instrumentation and methods, but "it's not nice".  I asked him if it was related to jump blues, and he seemed to think that was plausible, but nothing more.

This is a thing??

Answer (score 5):

"Rude Jazz" appears to be Blecha's own term for a musical trend localized in the Pacific northwest, but which is not explicitly defined in his books. It seems to have been a hard-driving, jazz-inflected version of 1950s R&B and rock 'n' roll.

From *Stomp and Shout*, "Introduction: The Sea-Port Beat":

> Once upon a time—decades prior to grunge rock being even a gleam in Sub Pop’s eye—the Pacific Northwest was the birthing ground to a rockin’ R&B scene that created its own unique strain of rock ’n’ roll. This was a distinctive rude-jazz–tinged mutation that erupted in the seaport towns of Seattle, Tacoma, and Portland between the approximate years of 1958 and 1965 and would come to be called the original Northwest Sound—or in some circles the Sea-Port Beat or Sea-Port Sound. (via [book preview on Scribd](https://www.scribd.com/book/626223494/Stomp-and-Shout-R-B-and-the-Origins-of-Northwest-Rock-and-Roll))

From *Sonic Boom*, "Chapter 6: That Sound":

> The task of creating a Northwest Sound would be left to ... players whose musicality was admittedly informed by jazz traditions, but who would lean more toward the emerging trends of rhythm and blues, and then rock 'n' roll. In fact, this regional musical mutation — which was forged in the rowdy dancehalls of the areas biggest seaport towns of Seattle, Portland, and Tacoma — was initially referred to ... as the "Sea-Port Beat." In its earliest phase, the music was based on a shared repertoire of recent and current R&B hits and a lot of "rude jazz" saxophone-led tunes.

> The "Sea-Port Beat," or "original Northwest Sound," as first defined by Seattle's Dave Lewis Combo was essentially a regional sub-strain of rock 'n' roll that was firmly anchored in the West Coast R&B previously honed by Ray Charles and Richard Berry — along with the horn-driven sounds of the bands of Big Jay McNeely, Bobby "Blue" Bland, and Hank Ballard. But the critical ingredient ... was a tendency to ... alter their overall vibe ... in a way that rocked hard and had no room for rhythmic subtlety. (page 39)

*Little Green Thing* (album) by Dave Lewis

And from *Music in Washington*:

> Just consider some of the local African-American "rude jazz" and rhythm and blues whose names alone evoke good times gone by, like Tacoma's Swinging Esquires and Seattle's Savoy Boys and Billy Tolles and the Vibrators. (pages 8–9)

Aside from these, I found no other references to "rude jazz" via Google or Google Scholar.

Comment: Thanks for that!  For what it's worth, he says he got the term from older musicians he has interviewed, so I don't think it's his own term, but maybe not widespread.